# What format of Content type should i use when upload GPX file to s3 storage

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

i have InputStream of .gpx file, i try to save this file on s3, what Media type should i use?
Is exsists "text/gpx" format?

Answer (score 0):

It is either `application/gpx+xml` or `application/octet-stream` that are correct for GPX files